# Setting style of element in vue js not work

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm practicing vue.js, I'm trying to change the height of my div I've used v-bind but it doesn't change the height. Whats wrong?

My element

```
<v-toolbar-title slot="extension" v-bind:style="setHeight()"></v-toolbar-title>
```

Script

```
<script>
  export default {
    data : () => ({
      sideNav: {
        model: false,
        type: 'temporary',
        clipped: false,
        floating: false,
        mini: false,
        stateless:true,

      },
      isMobile: false

    }),
    methods:{
        setHeight(){
            return{
                height :  screen.height - (screen.height / 2) + '!important'
            }
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        //var maxHeight = screen.height / 2;
        //alert(screen.height - (screen.height / 2))
    }
  }
</script>
```

Like the equivalent of

```
 document.getElementById("div").style.height = height;
```

Comment: You forgot the `px` part of the string: `screen.height - (screen.height / 2) + 'px !important'` (https://jsfiddle.net/yuriy636/j6tra9o1/)

Comment: Oh thanks I need a sleep